# Integrating angular+spring boot application with third party application

Tags: angular, spring-boot

There is a requirement of integrating my angular application with their main portal.When any user from there portal clicks on my application link. My angular application should be opned in new window by first validating request through headers which they will send when user clicks on my application link.
I have to first validate the request in spring boot and then show home/welcome page in new window.Please help.

Comment: please add some code showing what it is you have tried

Comment: I have not yet started...just asking as to follow one approach to code.